# why show compile error can't find project vba?

Tags: excel, vba

i need help  adjusting  my code (transfer data from userform to worksheet
it shows me error compile can't find project library  then sit on this word "trim"

```html
Private Sub ButtonNew_Click()
    Dim Ad As String
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim xx As Long
    ''''''''''''''''''''
    For c = 1 To ContColmn
        Ad = Cells(1, c).Address(0, 0)
        If Len(Trim(Me.Controls(Ad).Value)) = 0 Then
           MsgBox "address: " & Me.Controls("xx" & c).Caption & " empty", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxRight + vbMsgBoxRtlReading, "empty cell"
           Me.Controls(Ad).SetFocus
            Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Sheet2
        Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        For c = 1 To ContColmn
            Ad = Cells(1, c).Address(0, 0)
            .Cells(Lr, c).Value = Me.Controls(Ad).Value
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    A1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets(2).Range("A2:A5000")) + 1
    MsgBox "ok"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Check your VB project references for missing items.  What's being flagged is not what's missing.

Comment: Your code is likely fine. The error suggests that in `Tools>>References` menu you are referencing a library that doesn't exist in your computer. Head over to that menu and uncheck whatever it is (or if it's needed to make this VBA subroutine run, then figure out how to install it or choose the appropriate version that is installed).

Comment: jnevill  what exactly uncheck the tool  from reference  need help,please

Comment: Tim Williams   i apreciate your reply   but  how i can check the item from reference

Comment: See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx or https://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2018/12/missing-reference-excel-vba.html for example

Comment: i do this  as the websites  but   the message error changed "you can't find specified  object"

Comment: this tool  "MISSING Library"probably solve  my problem  but  unfortunately  it is not existed in reference i no know why ? maybe version office 2010